# ubuntu shows 27 gb ram out of 32 gb

Tags: 20.04, ram

free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          27923       12347        6956          55        8620       14922
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Also I switch my gpu from intel to nvidia so there no additional ram to integrated graphics but I am still not sure

```
prime-select query
nvidia
```

I extended to 32 gb. System monitor says 27.3/32 gb.

```
dmesg  | grep -i 'Memory:'
[    0.038296] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.038297] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000bffff]
[    0.038298] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.038299] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09a00000-0x09dfffff]
[    0.038300] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09f00000-0x09f0efff]
[    0.038301] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f50000-0xb4f50fff]
[    0.038302] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f5d000-0xb4f5dfff]
[    0.038302] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f5e000-0xb4f5efff]
[    0.038303] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f71000-0xb4f71fff]
[    0.038303] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f72000-0xb4f72fff]
[    0.038304] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f81000-0xb4f81fff]
[    0.038305] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4f82000-0xb5090fff]
[    0.038306] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb534a000-0xb534afff]
[    0.038307] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb534f000-0xb534ffff]
[    0.038308] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbab69000-0xbbd68fff]
[    0.038309] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc9f7f000-0xccf7efff]
[    0.038309] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xccf7f000-0xcdf7efff]
[    0.038310] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcdf7f000-0xcdffefff]
[    0.038311] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xce000000-0xcfffffff]
[    0.038311] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.038312] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.038312] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.038312] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff]
[    0.038313] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfdf00000-0xfdffffff]
[    0.038313] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe0fffff]
[    0.038313] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe100000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.038314] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec01fff]
[    0.038314] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec02000-0xfec0ffff]
[    0.038315] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec10000-0xfec10fff]
[    0.038315] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec11000-0xfec1ffff]
[    0.038315] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec20000-0xfec20fff]
[    0.038316] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec21000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.038316] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xfed81fff]
[    0.038317] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed82000-0xfedfffff]
[    0.038317] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
[    0.038317] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
[    0.038318] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.082068] Memory: 28412460K/29208636K available (16393K kernel code, 3512K rwdata, 10492K rodata, 2904K init, 5724K bss, 795916K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.127150] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.527562] Freeing initrd memory: 58156K
[    0.792722] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
[    0.793289] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2904K
[    0.794020] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
[    0.794501] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1796K
```

---

I have uma frame buffer size in bios with options 1/2/4. I set from 4 to 2 gb. So now I have 30/32 gb. 29.2 gb actually.I don't know why on windows and ubuntu it doesn't change from amd graphics to nvidia. On lenovo in bios it has suitable graphics or only uma (amd). If I set to 1 gb it has 30/32gb ram.

Comment: How much memory is being reserved during boot? Do: `dmesg  | grep -i 'Memory:'` and edit it into your question.

Comment: Depending on your system, you might also have to go to the BIOS settings and disable the onboard video as well to free up the shared memory.  Without knowing your system it is hard to say.

Comment: I extended to 32gb for work purposes

Comment: Well, then you need to update your question with the new output for `free -m`. But yes, and as mentioned by @Terrance, your BIOS seems to be withholding a lot of memory. I also have 32 gigs and get: `Memory: 32540404K/33380928K available ...`